# Tags are invisible when oneboxed

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Tags for meta posts are practically invisible when oneboxed on chat:

[image]

To see this bug, [click here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/2835444#2835444).

Posts from the main site work fine.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The API was returning unreadable colors for this site's tag styling. [This is fixed now](https://api.stackexchange.com/2.0/info?site=meta.dba&filter=!3iry-SpHdDIw._uF), so tags in future oneboxes will be readable.